# Find nearest gas station using google maps v2 in android and want to display the route to it

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2

I can find the nearby gas stations using the following code but how can I find the nearest one?

```
StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
        googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + source.latitude + "," + source.longitude);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=" + PROOXIMITY_RADIUS);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&types=" + "gas_station");
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + GOOGLE_API_KEY);
```

Using the above code, I am creating the url to get the nearest gas stations.

```
public String read(String httpUrl){
        String httpData = "";
        InputStream stream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(httpUrl);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();
            stream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                buf.append(line);
            }
            httpData = buf.toString();
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("HttpRequestHandler" , e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                stream.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("HttpRequestHandler" , e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return httpData;
    }
```

After this , I am parsing the response.

But what I want to do is I want to find the nearest one? I can calculate the distance using latitude and longitude but I think there must be some easier way?

Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straight forward way is using the `rankby=distance` parameter in your request.

> **rankby** — Specifies the order in which results are listed. Note that rankby must not be included if radius (described under Required parameters above) is specified. Possible values are:
>
> **prominence (default)**. This option sorts results based on their importance. Ranking will favor prominent places within the specified area. Prominence can be affected by a place's ranking in Google's index, global popularity, and other factors.
>
> **distance**. This option biases search results in ascending order by their distance from the specified location. When distance is specified, one or more of keyword, name, or type is required.

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests

The code snippet is the following (you remove `radius` and add `rankby`)

```
StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + source.latitude + "," + source.longitude);
googlePlacesUrl.append("&rankby=distance");
googlePlacesUrl.append("&type=" + "gas_station");
googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + GOOGLE_API_KEY);
```

You can also remove the `sensor` parameter that was deprecated a long time ago and not used anymore. Note that `types` parameter is not valid you should use `type` according to the documentation.

> **type** — Restricts the results to places matching the specified type. Only one type may be specified (if more than one type is provided, all types following the first entry are ignored)

The nearest gas station will be the first in the response.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot xomena. That really helped a lot.